# Isssues installing anything other than ubuntu on laptop(HP Stream 11)

Tags: slackware

I've been trying for a week now. Ive bought this laptop with windows 8 so that works. I successfully installed Ubuntu but I'm trying to switch to Slackware or Arch.

Most OS's wont boot from the USB. Like with Debian I just get straight into grub.

But with Slackware I can boot into its installer but it when I use `lsblk` the only disk that comes up is my own flash drive.

The SSD in the laptop doesn't appear in the list. I'm confused about what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have grub, you can go around the issue and boot directly from the iso file.

1. Boot Ubuntu and create a folder called `iso` in `/boot`. and put the iso files of the distributions you wish to install.
2. Modify the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file manually (ignoring the warning inside the file) by adding entries to the iso files added. Reference for the entries can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Boot_entries). Modify the entries according to the actual iso filenames.
3. Save the file and reboot.

You should have new entries for the iso files which you can boot directly.

P.S. the `grub.cfg` file will be updated by `update-grub` in Ubuntu, so if a new kernel is installed or you run this command manually your grub.cfg is replaced and your entries to the iso files are gone.